# Why does the query only returns data from when not contained within a function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Why does this code work (As far as it pulls back an empty "CustomerObject" viewable in Chrome console

```
var CustomerObject = Parse.Object.extend("CustomerObject");
var retrieve = new Parse.Query(CustomerObject);  
retrieve.equalTo("customernumber", $('#searchnumber').val()); 
        retrieve.first({ 
            success: function(retrieveResults) 

        {

        }

    });
        var cname = retrieve.get("customername");  
        var cnumber = retrieve.get("customernumber");
```

But this code inside a function does not return any "CustomerObject" when the user clicks the search button?

HTML

```
  <input type="text" name="searchnumber" id="searchnumber" value="" placeholder="Customer Number"/>  
    <button type="submit" onclick = "search" >Find</button>
```

JS

```
function search() {
var CustomerObject = Parse.Object.extend("CustomerObject");
var retrieve = new Parse.Query(CustomerObject);  
retrieve.equalTo("customernumber", $('#searchnumber').val()); 
        retrieve.first({ 
            success: function(retrieveResults) 

        {

        }

    });
        var cname = retrieve.get("customername");  
        var cnumber = retrieve.get("customernumber"); 

  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing bracket `<button type="submit" onclick = "search() " >Find</button>`